# WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto: when running setup.py

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I'm trying to install the Quickshot application on Ubuntu 12.04/12.10, and am running into the following error whenever I run setup.py (it doesn't matter if I just run setup.py, setup.py check, setup.py build, or setup.py clean--I haven't tried setup.py install).

```
    WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
    bin/quickshot
    hooks/quickshot-crashdb.conf
    hooks/source_quickshot.py
    po/quickshot.pot
    quickshot.desktop
    run.sh
```

I'm also pasting a copy of the setup.py file in. On Ubuntu 12.10, the bin/quickshot doesn't trigger, but the rest of them do.  Any suggestions on what to fix, to get this working are greatly appreciated.

Thanks, and have a great weekend (what's left of it):)
Patrick.

setup.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    ### BEGIN LICENSE
    # Copyright (C) 2010 Benjamin Humphrey <humphreybc@gmail.co>
    #This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it 
    #under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 3, as published 
    #by the Free Software Foundation.
    #
    #This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but 
    #WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranties of 
    #MERCHANTABILITY, SATISFACTORY QUALITY, or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
    #PURPOSE.  See the GNU General Public License for more details.
    #
    #You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along 
    #with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
    ### END LICENSE

    ###################### DO NOT TOUCH THIS (HEAD TO THE SECOND PART) ######################

    try:
        import DistUtilsExtra.auto
    except ImportError:
        import sys
        print >> sys.stderr, 'To build quickshot you need https://launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra'
        sys.exit(1)

    assert DistUtilsExtra.auto.__version__ >= '2.10', 'needs DistUtilsExtra.auto >= 2.10'
    import os


    def update_data_path(prefix, oldvalue=None):

        try:
            fin = file('quickshot/quickshotconfig.py', 'r')
            fout = file(fin.name + '.new', 'w')

            for line in fin:            
                fields = line.split(' = ') # Separate variable from value
                if fields[0] == '__quickshot_data_directory__':
                     # update to prefix, store oldvalue
                    if not oldvalue:
                        oldvalue = fields[1]
                        line = "%s = '%s'\n" % (fields[0], prefix)
                    else: # restore oldvalue
                        line = "%s = %s" % (fields[0], oldvalue)
                fout.write(line)

            fout.flush()
            fout.close()
            fin.close()
            os.rename(fout.name, fin.name)
        except (OSError, IOError), e:
            print ("ERROR: Can't find quickshot/quickshotconfig.py")
            sys.exit(1)
        return oldvalue


    def update_desktop_file(datadir):

        try:
            fin = file('quickshot.desktop.in', 'r')
            fout = file(fin.name + '.new', 'w')

            for line in fin:            
                 if 'Icon=' in line:
                    line = "Icon=%s\n" % (datadir + 'media/icon.png')
                fout.write(line)
            fout.flush()
            fout.close()
            fin.close()
            os.rename(fout.name, fin.name)
        except (OSError, IOError), e:
            print ("ERROR: Can't find quickshot.desktop.in")
            sys.exit(1)


    class InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory(DistUtilsExtra.auto.install_auto):
        def run(self):
            if self.root or self.home:
                print "WARNING: You don't use a standard --prefix installation, take care that you eventually " \
                "need to update quickly/quicklyconfig.py file to adjust __quickly_data_directory__. You can " \
                "ignore this warning if you are packaging and uses --prefix."
            previous_value = update_data_path(self.prefix + '/share/quickshot/')
            update_desktop_file(self.prefix + '/share/quickshot/')
            DistUtilsExtra.auto.install_auto.run(self)
            update_data_path(self.prefix, previous_value)



    ##################################################################################
    ###################### YOU SHOULD MODIFY ONLY WHAT IS BELOW ######################
    ##################################################################################

    DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(
        name='quickshot',
        version='0.0.83',
        license='GPL-3',
        author='Benjamin Humphrey, Tommy Brunn',
        author_email='humphreybc@gmail.com',
        url='https://launchpad.net/quickshot',
        description='Quickshot is a program designed for capturing a large number of screenshots in different languages. It is principally designed for use with the Ubuntu Manual Project, but should be able to be tweaked for different projects and uses.',
        #long_description='Here a longer description',
        cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory}
        )
```

If the spaces aren't right in the setup.py file, that's due to having to manually indent them here. They should be assumed to be correct in the actual file, as it does install under Ubuntu 10.04, 10,10, and possibly 11.04/11.10 (I haven't verified the last two).

Also the results of setup.py build are the following:

```
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/capture
    copying quickshot/lib/capture/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/capture
    copying quickshot/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot
    copying quickshot/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/server
    copying quickshot/lib/server/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/server
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/resolution
    copying quickshot/lib/resolution/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/resolution
    copying quickshot/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/screenshot_list.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/user_account.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/screenshot_compare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/about.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/credits.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/graphics_confirm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/licence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/dialogue.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/graphics_change.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/user_details.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/screenshot_detail.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    copying quickshot/gui/project_selection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/gui
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/account
    copying quickshot/lib/account/environment.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/account
    copying quickshot/lib/account/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/quickshot/lib/account
    running build_i18n
    intltool-update -p -g quickshot
    running build_icons
    running build_help
    WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
      bin/quickshot
      hooks/quickshot-crashdb.conf
      hooks/source_quickshot.py
      quickshot.desktop
      run.sh
```

Here are the results of setup.py install:

```
    running install
    ERROR: Can't find quickshot/quickshotconfig.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 103, in <module>
        cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory}
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/DistUtilsExtra/auto.py", line 100, in setup
        distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setup.py", line 83, in run
        previous_value = update_data_path(self.prefix + '/share/quickshot/')
      File "setup.py", line 54, in update_data_path
        sys.exit(1)
    NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined
```

Comment: The results of setup.py build are the following:

Comment: A *warning* is not the same as an *error*. Did the library itself install?

Comment: I haven't tried setup.py install yet. Since I was getting the warnings, I wasn't sure if I should try that or not.

I'm posting the results of setup.py install at the bottom of my original post, as it's about 360 characters too long for the comment setcion.

Comment: Isn't there a Ubuntu package you can install? Or are you trying to develop this package?

Comment: The ubuntu package is stale. It hasn't been worked on since either Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.04. I'm mainly trying to find out what's broken, and seeing whether it still works for 12.04/12.10. If it's a lost cause, then they'll abandon it completely.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with the Distutils Extension used; you are firmly in Ubuntu-built extensions here. Perhaps this belongs on AskUbuntu instead?

Comment: It appears that the branch that I downloaded (the lp:quickshot branch) doesn't have the file, but the release (current stable or in this case OLD stable) does have it. I'm going to try downloading the release branch, and see if that installs properly. 

It appears that I was pointed to the wrong location for downloading.

Comment: This might work better on the Ubuntu SE site, I can migrate if you want (please don't cross-post)?

Comment: It is definitely a bug in the setup.py code. I suggest you contact the package author about the installation instructions / commands needed to deploy the package.